# How to Open Multiple Program from DVD (BAT file)

Tags: batch-file

I want to open multiple program from DVD drive using BAT file. My below current code work perfectly on my PC since the CD Drive considered as ("E:\").

I need your help to modify the code so its work in any PC regardless the drive letter.

```
@echo off
cd "E:\Program\XYZ"
start ABC.exe

cd "E:\Program\"
start ABC.html

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

`wmic` is a powerful utiltiy to get all sort of information
(try `wmic logicaldisk get name,description,drivetype,volumename`).
Put a `for /f` loop around, and you're done:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=5" get name /value^|find "="') do set "drive=%%a"
echo %drive%
cd /d "%drive%\Program\"
```

Note: if there are more than one CD-drive, this will return the last one.